# Generating mask array using logical operators

Tags: arrays, matlab, casting, geometry, mask

How can I improve on my mask array to generate a mask for different geometries using logical operators `&` and `|`?

Part of the code (regarding mask) at the moment generates a square with a radius inside of it.

```
mask = ((x-side/4).^2 + (y-side/4).^2) > rcore^2;
max_error = tol;
while max_error > tol/100
for row = 2:m-1
  for col = 2:m-1      
    if mask(row,col) == 1
       r(row,col) = (t(row+1,col) + t(row-1,col) + t(row,col+1) + t(row,col-1) 
                 - 4*t(row,col))/4;
       t(row,col) = t(row,col) + weight*r(row,col);
    end      
  end    
 end
max_error = max(max(abs(r)));
end
```

If specifics required, just comment!

Comment: You may want to explain more clearly what a *mask* in this context means; this looks similar to a *stencil* in OpenGL. For the construction of said array, you may want to do some reading on *rasterization*.

Comment: See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)